How do you increase the DMA buffer size allowed by dma_alloc_coherent?
I need to get dma_alloc_coherent to return a 16MB buffer, but the max size I can request is 4MB. Is does not appear that CMA is running, otherwise I think I could add cma=16M to the command line. I can loop through allocating 4MB and see if they're contiguous to get my 16MB buffer, but I don't think that's a great solution. I'm running kernel 6.2.0-39-generic. Is there a similar command line parameter I can pass when CMA isn't running to override the 4MB limit?
